# Probability that the tenth card is black if at most one was black out of the first nine

Tags: probability, combinations

> Assume you draw 10 cards from a standard 52 card deck without replacement.
>   What is is the probability the 10th card is black for the two cases below:
>
> a) the first nine cards drawn are not black
>
> b) more difficult- same question only now you know there is at most one black chosen in the previous nine.

Clearly the answer to part (a) is $26/43$ . Not sure how to do part (b).

Comment: Maybe you could explain what have you done so far to get the solution?

Comment: @mihir   I do not know what to do

Comment: Hint:  you'll need to compute the probability of getting $0$ black cards in the first nine draws, and the probability of getting exactly $1$ black card in the first nine draws.

Comment: Assume first that exactly one black card is chosen in the 9 and then weight the two answers using conditional probabilty

Comment: Is the probability first nine are not black  and the 10th  is black given by (9C26/9C52)* 26/43 ?

Comment: Is the probability first nine are not black  and the 10th  is black given by (9C26/9C52)* 26/43 ?   is the probability one of the first nine is black and the 10th is black given by (8C26)*(1C26)/(9C52) *25/43?

Answer (score 1):

Ways of getting 9 red cards = ${26\choose9} = A$, say

Ways of getting 8 red & 1 black card = ${26\choose8}{26\choose1} = B$, say

then compute weighted probability

$$\left(A\cdot\frac{26}{43} + B\cdot\frac{25}{43}\right)\over(A+B)$$